# UNIX timestamp(0): Europe/London returns UTC+1

Tags: php, timezone, timestamp, unix-timestamp, timezone-offset

Learning dates and they're giving me hard time right now.

```
$london = new DateTime();
$london->setTimestamp(0);
$london->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));

echo $london ->format('d-m-Y H-i-s');
```

result:

```
01-01-1970 01-00-00
```

Shouldn't be London in `UTC +0:00` therefore midnight? For example, New York returns 19:00 of the previous date which is correctly `UTC -5:00`. Moscow returns `01-01-1970 03-00-00` which is again incorrect (`UTC +3:00` as opposed to `UTC +4:00`)

When not using `->setTimestamp`, the London current time renders correctly, though.

Livecode: [http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fddf5e479f19441f6bbda0b3fde41b3a0ab02a2e)

Also, my local timezone is `Europe/Prague` (`UTC +1:00`). Tested with `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London')` as well.

I presume there's some error in my logic?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because apparently, Great Britain was on [British Summer Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time) on January 1, 1970, one hour ahead of UTC (emphasis mine):

> An inquiry during the winter of 1959–60, in which 180 national organisations were consulted, revealed a slight preference for a change to all-year GMT+1, but the length of summer time was extended as a trial rather than the domestic use of Greenwich Mean Time abolished.[6] A further inquiry during 1966–67 led the government of Harold Wilson to introduce the British Standard Time experiment, **with Britain remaining on GMT+1 throughout the year.** This took place between 27 October 1968 and 31 October 1971, when there was a reversion to the previous arrangement.

timeanddate.com's [Time Zone Converter](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?iso=19700101T01&p1=136&p2=0&p3=&p4=&p5=&p6=&p7=&p8=&p9=&p10=&p11=&p12=) is a great tool for finding out stuff like this.

Comment: @hohner lol! Thinking about it, though, I wouldn't be surprised if this had a duplicate somewhere....

Comment: Wow, I've never known. Makes me wanna dust of my nonexistent pile of history books. I guess Russia did something similar?

Comment: @DavidL: MSK (Moscow standard time) was UTC+3 until 2011 (and UTC+4 summer time (MSD)). Now MSK is UTC+4 all year round.